# How to fix arguments did not match any overloaded call in Python?

Tags: python

I have a painter created and the code below gives me the error

```
"TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  fillRect(self, QRectF, Union[QBrush, QColor, Qt.GlobalColor, int, QGradient]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'"
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

Here is the code

```py
 def drawBoardSquares(self, painter):
    '''draw all the square on the board'''
    # setting the default colour of the brush
    brush = QBrush(Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern)  # calling SolidPattern to a variable
    brush.setColor(QColor(245, 173, 66))  # setting color to orange
    painter.setBrush(brush)  # setting brush color to painter

    for row in range(0, Board.boardHeight):
        for col in range(0, Board.boardWidth):
            painter.save()
            colTransformation = self.squareWidth() * col  # setting this value equal the transformation in the column direction
            rowTransformation = self.squareHeight() * row  # setting this value equal the transformation in the row direction

            painter.translate(colTransformation, rowTransformation)
            painter.fillRect(col,row)
            painter.fillRect(self.squareWidth(),self.squareHeight())# passing the above variables and methods as a parameter
            painter.restore()

            # changing the colour of the brush so that a checkered board is drawn
            if brush.color() == QColor(245, 173, 66):  # if the brush color of square is orange
                brush.setColor(QColor(110, 110, 110))  # set the nex color of the square to black
            else:  # if its black, then set the next square to orange
                brush.setColor(QColor(245, 173, 66))
```

I have tried putting different parameters into fillRect but it is still ow working.

Comment: `argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'` Are you passing the right parameters? It seems you are passing an int when you should be passing a `QRectF`

Answer (score 0):

See you just have to match that the number of arguments given in function call is equal to number of arguments required in your function which you have defined.

Comment: Ok, so how do I rewrite it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).